# Maximum serialization depth exceeded

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I get the error "maximum serialization depth exceeded" when trying to push new data on MongoDB.  When unit testing on localhost with MongoDB Community, it works with no problems.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm also not seeing a Circular Reference.

This is the function that kicks off the saving of the data.  First to my local cache then to the cloud (MongoDB).

```
///Calling function
public async Task AddComment(Range item, Comment commentItem)
{
    try
    {
        //Save to local cache
        item.Comments.Add(commentItem);

        //Next save to cloud
        await CloudStorage.AddComment(item.User.ID, item.ID, commentItem);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

//-->ERROR HAPPENS LAST LINE HERE<--
public async Task<UpdateResult> AddComment(string ownerID, string rangeID, Comment comment)
{
    var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Where(u => u.ID == ownerID &&
                                                  u.Content.Any(i => i.ID == rangeID));
    var update = Builders<User>.Update.Push(c => c.Content[-1].Comments, comment);
    return await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update); //<- THIS THROWS ERROR
}
```

Here's the unit test that works with localhost.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestInsertComment()
{
    //Arrange
    var owner = "OWNER";

    var ownerData = collection.Find(u => u.Username.Equals(owner)).FirstOrDefault();
    var ownerID = ownerData?.ID;
    var range = ownerData?.Content.FirstOrDefault();

    var newComment = new Comment
    {
        User = range?.User,
        Content = "Some comment",
        IsLive = true
    };

    //Act
    var results = _cloudStorageService.AddComment(ownerID, range?.ID, newComment);
    results.Wait();

    var insertedID = collection.Find(u => u.Username.Equals(owner))
                               .FirstOrDefault().Content.FirstOrDefault()?
                               .Comments.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID.Equals(newComment.ID))?.ID;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(newComment.ID, insertedID);
}
```

**UPDATE:** One thing I noticed is if the same user tries to add a comment to their range, that's the only time this error occurs.  If another user adds a comment, it works just fine.  And the unit test works fine all the time regardless of if it's same user or other user.

Comment: There is not any real difference in the MongoDB server between those in the Atlas cluster scheme and the community edition builds available. Current "sandbox" instances are MongoDB 3.4. If you see an error between environments you will more likely have something else different happening. If you believe different, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can reliably reproduce the issue. Therefore code and data complete, or whatever needs to happen to consistently trigger the error.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for your reply.  I'll look into it further and if need be post a complete example.  I noticed times when it worked live and other times when it didn't.  I'll follow that path and see where it leads as I'm able to consistently duplicate the issue.  The confusing part is it works every time when I chose localhost as the server which is throwing me off.

Comment: If you could even post that "minimal" code here it would be a start. There might just be something that someone else can see or even reproduce. The point of the help article was to at least get you to the point where there was a "test case" and not asking people to trawl through miles of code. So sharing your "test case" would be a good thing at this point.

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn  I edited my post above with code.  It may be overkill but I wanted to paint a good picture.  Interested to get your feedback on what you see.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help @NeilLunn I resolved the issue by accident cleaning up my code.  See answer below for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow!

So I decided to step away from the error I was getting and perform code clean-up instead.  While doing so, I stumbled upon a clean-up item I've been ignoring for a while which was to remove all SomeAsyncTask.Wait() references from the code and replace with await SomeAsyncTask.  Well in doing so, I found this little nugget:

```
var commentItem = new Comment
{
    User = GetCurrentUserExtData(),
    Content = NewCommentText
}

public User GetCurrentUserExtData(string ID = null)
{
    var user = new User();
    var data = DataStore.GetUser(ID);
    data.Wait();
    user = data.Result;

    return user;
}
```

GetCurrentUserExtData had the SomeAsyncTask.Wait() task in it.  Changed it to:

```
var commentItem = new Comment
{
    Content = NewCommentText,
    User = await DataStore.GetUser()
}
```

And NO MORE maximum serialization depth exceeded error!  I didn't think at all that would be related but it was!  Needless to say, REMOVE ALL .WAIT() REFERENCES and find a way to use await if using async methods.

Comment: Related: [C# Developers: Stop Calling .Result](https://montemagno.com/c-sharp-developers-stop-calling-dot-result/)

Comment: Right. It wasn't locking up my UI but didn't play nicely with MongoDB. Either way, not a good idea.